# How to shorten \hline in a matrix

Tags: spacing, matrices, rules

I indicate blocks in a matrix using `\hline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      a & b\\
      \hline
      c & d
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
\endinput
```

[image: example image]

However, for normal point sizes the document is generated in (11pt), the rule drawn crosses over the matrix borders. (For poster sizes, this is not the case.)

How can I shorten the rule on both sides so that this does not occur, while still preserving the vertical spacing provided by `\hline`?

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4778) that illustrates your problem? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Alenanno: done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `bmatrix` environment and also the other matrix related ones use internally `array`, but do a backup after the left delimiter and before the right one. Therefore the rule made by `\hline` presents the problem you're facing.

There are technical reasons for using a backup rather than removing the intercolumn spacing at either end with `@{}`. There are two different solutions; one is to use `booktabs` and the other one is making a new environment for matrices with rule separators.

The first is more elegant, in my opinion. Both require you to specify the columns in some way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{booktabs} % required for the first solution

% this is for the second solution; the argument is the number of columns
\newenvironment{lbmatrix}[1]
  {\left[\array{@{}*{#1}{c}@{}}}
  {\endarray\right]}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
  a & b\\
  \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
  c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{lbmatrix}{2}
  a & b\\
  \hline
  c & d
\end{lbmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try switching to `array` instead, apparently the `bmatrix` environment doesn't work well with horizontal lines (judging from what I've seen in other forums).

If you switch between `\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}`, as suggested by daleif, `\begin{array}{cc}`, it will change the appearance.

[image: matrices]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \[ \left[ \begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
    a & b \\ \hline
    c & d
    \end{array} \right]
    %
    \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
    a & b \\ \hline
    c & d
    \end{array} \right]
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: looks better if you use `@{}cc@{}`.

Comment: @daleif Thanks, included that version too. :D