# Matrix: hline is cut by cmidrule

Tags: matrices, arrays, booktabs, block

I want to emphasize a block structure in a matrix by both, vertical and horizontal lines. Since I am using bmatrix as matrix environment I had the issues as in [How to shorten \hline in a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139275/how-to-shorten-hline-in-a-matrix).

I very much liked the first solution mentioned there using booktabs, because it calculates vertical spacings in a nice fashion and centers the horizontal lines correctly (e.g. with 2 rows the middle of the equal sign before the matrix will exactly be at the same height as the line drawn by cmidrule).

However, I still want to add vertical lines, therefore I use [cc|cc] as optional argument. But then the vertical line is interrupted by the vertical line.

Is there an easy way out? As far as I could figure out, the clue about cmidrule is the trim option which I couldn't find for hline or cline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{booktabs} % required for the first solution

%matrix environment redef
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
   \hskip -\arraycolsep
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\array{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}[c|c]
  a & b\\      \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
  c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I don't think the `[bpv]matrix` environments can take an optional environment of the form `cc|cc`.

Comment: Related: [Vertical table lines are discontinuous with booktabs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88929/17423).

Comment: @Mico: With the redefinition of the matrix environment as above it is possible to supply column options.

Comment: @Mico: See here: (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36757/how-does-this-macro-for-augmented-matrices-work)

Comment: Ah, it would have been easier to understand if you'd written `\begin{bmatrix}[c|c]`. At least that's what I think the intent is, since the body of the matrix contains just two columns, not four.

Comment: right, corrected it. My local example has 2x2 blocks, that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the horizontal and vertical lines to intersect, you can't use the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package.

Here's a solution that uses just a basic `array` environment. This solution is similar to the one given by @Alenanno in the posting you provided a link to; the main difference is that the `@{}` directives have been replaced with `@{\,}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$
\left[ \begin{array}{@{\,} c|c @{\,}}
  u & v\\      
  \hline
  w & x \\
\end{array} \right]
$
\end{document}
```

*Addendum*: If you need a bit of extra vertical separation between the rows, you could load the `array` package and issue the instruction `\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}` in the preamble. This may be particularly useful if the submatrices have diacritics (such as `\bar{...}`) that would otherwise come too close to the `\hline`, as is the case with `\bar{d}` in the example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for "\extrarowheight" macro
\begin{document}
$
\left[  \begin{array}{@{\,} c|c @{\,}}
  a & b\\      
  \hline
  c & \bar{d} \\
\end{array}  \right]
$
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
$
\left[  \begin{array}{@{\,} c|c @{\,}}
  a & b\\      
  \hline
  c & \bar{d} \\
\end{array}  \right]
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. So there's no way include extra height only at the columns seperated by hline with just one command (similar as booktabs' cmidrule does)? If you replace u by \bar{u} in your example the bar will almost touch the line. 2. Why is the above solution with array not the same as with the redefinition of the bmatrix environment (concerning the length of hline)?

Comment: @user3733247 - I suppose `\usepackage{array}` and `\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}` count as *two* commands, not one... Incidentally, since there's no `\hline` above `u` in my example, I don't think I understand your claim that "the bar [in \bar{u}] will almost touch the line".

Comment: @user3733247 - Regarding your second comment: I noted in a direct comment on your posting that it's not possible to redefine the `bmatrix` environment the way you propose to do, i.e., by adding an "optional" argument such as `cc|cc`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant w of course. And an optional argument seems possible as mentioned above a minute ago;)

Comment: @user3733247 - Thanks, I now understand what the redefinition of `\env@matrix` does. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be flexible enough to permit a directive such as `\begin{bmatrix}[@{}c|c@{}]` without producing a bad collision between the brackets, the `\hline`, and the body of the matrix. I'd stick with the `array` solution given in my answer.

Comment: Well, okay, then for me it seems like there's no nice solution. But you helped me a lot anyway, thanks a lot. For my first problem I found http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65127/extra-vertical-space-after-hline-causes-a-gap-in-the-right-border-of-an-array .

Comment: @dbacc - The link you provide uses (typographic) struts. Very fine control of the lines is possible that way.

Comment: In your second example the vertical line is too long.